# How to write PhpStorm intelligence plugin?

Tags: plugins, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2016.1.

I'm using a chinese-written php framework. Unfortunately I found that there is no intelligence in PhpStorm for Model-classes of this framework.

I want to write intelligence plugin for this framework. Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: 1) Maybe it can be solved by proper PHPDoc somehow? 2) Plugin must be written using Java -- you can have a look at some existing framework-support plugins: https://github.com/Sorien/silex-idea-plugin ; https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin and [so on](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/index?pr=phpStorm&category_id=43) 3) http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Plugin+Development

Creating Your First Plugin http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html